# Keeping Single Database Connection on Android

Tags: android, database, singleton, blocking

This question seems very similar to many I have read but then again, I did not find any code that would satisfy me. (or I am too sleepy to realize that)

I have a singleton database helper to ensure only one of them exists. The problem is not here. I encounter a problem when trying to ensure only one database connection exists while still using `getReadableDatabase` and `getWritableDatabse` methods.

I know it returns the same reference in most cases and I can handle use of it but I don't know what to do in case I have read-only connection open (probably was running out of memory) and another thread wants to open a writable connection. I would like to block the writing thread until read-only connection is closed and then attempt to open a writable connection.

How do you do that? That, probably, can be done in Java only with some thread locking but not sure which methods should be used.

P.S. In case I am missing something - feel free to show me how it should be done in another way.

Comment: ` running out of memory` ?? what is the size of your db ?

Comment: I had the same question a few weeks ago and I ended up implementing a content provider. Is it an overkill? Since the data is only gonna be accessed within the same application. But I do love how it abstracts away some of the complications with accessing SQLite database, plus it works really well with loaders too.

Comment: @Lucifer, my application is never the only app using memory.

Comment: @HangGuan, it seems so. Android developer guide says that content providers should not be used if data is only used within your application. I think content providers use way more CPU and memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gone through the same issues in the past and synchronization is the answer. Simply put, synchronize on the databasehelper instance.Or what you can do is create a wrapper method for getWritableDatabase and use the synchronized keyword in the method declatation. Then never call getReadableDatabase but just the wrapper method. Since getReadableDB and getWritableDB give the same reference, it's safe to do so. Make sense?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about it and that's what I did as a quick work-around but I want to keep the use of `getReadableDatabase` as it would succeed in most cases even though `getWritableDatabase` wouldn't. My app does very little writing and lot's of reading. That means it may conflict and yet it could successfully work on low memory if I used `getReadableDatabase`.